# iam not getting tool tip dojo 1.10 pie chart

Tags: charts, dojo

```
require(["dojox/charting/Chart", "dojox/charting/plot2d/Pie", "dojox/charting/action2d/Highlight","dojox/charting/action2d/MoveSlice" , "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip","dojox/charting/themes/MiamiNice","dojo/ready"],
      function(Chart, Pie, Highlight, MoveSlice, Tooltip, MiamiNice, ready){
      ready(function(){
        var chartTwo = new Chart("chartTwo");
        chartTwo.setTheme(MiamiNice)
         .addPlot("default", {
            type: Pie,
            font: "normal normal 11pt Tahoma",
            fontColor: "black",
            labelOffset: -30,
            radius: 80
        }).addSeries("Series A", [
            {y: 4, text: "Red",   stroke: "black", tooltip: "Red is 50%"},
            {y: 2, text: "Green", stroke: "black", tooltip: "Green is 25%"},
            {y: 1, text: "Blue",  stroke: "black", tooltip: "I am feeling Blue!"},
            {y: 1, text: "Other", stroke: "black", tooltip: "Mighty <strong>strong</strong><br>With two lines!"}
        ]);
        var anim_c = new Tooltip(chartTwo, "default");
        var anim_a = new MoveSlice(chartTwo, "default");
        var anim_b = new Highlight(chartTwo, "default");

        chartTwo.render();

      });
    });
```

Comment: please format the code properly. For formatting the code, select the code and press ctrl-k, which will automatically format the code. The above code is not readable.

Comment: As long as this code isn't formatted and a proper question isn't added, I cannot help you further. Please update your question, for now I voted to close this question as being unclear.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know because of your poor formatting but maybe you are missing the CSS needed to render the tooltip corrrectly?

Have you tried include this  CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dojoinstall/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
```

And set the claro CSS class on your body:

```
<body class="claro">
```

Also you mention explicitly 1.10, is that a regression from a previous version? If yes in that case the best way to proceed is to fill a bug on Dojo tracker.

Comment: yes i added in header css like <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/home/iportman/Desktop/SATHYAMFILES/dojo-release-1.10.0-src/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"> and   <body class="claro"> but unable to display chart
<div id="chartNode" style="width:800px;height:400px;"></div>
</body>